# Sync iOS7 device to PPC OSX 10.5.8?

Tags: macos, itunes, ios, data-synchronization

Can an iOS 7 device (iPad 2 for instance) be synchronized with a PPC Mac with OSX 10.5.8 and the latest iTunes for it, which I believe is iTunes 10.6.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because iOS 7 [requires iTunes version 11](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5337974) for syncing media (and firmware updates).